# <noscript> error after deployment even if javascript is enabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nginx, vue.js, deployment

After deployment got an error in network tab `We're sorry but app-frontend doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.`

Below is the code of `index.html` file of a vueJS app.

```
<body>
 <noscript>
   <strong>We're sorry but app-frontend doesn't work properly without 
   JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
 </noscript>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <script>
   if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
     navigator.serviceWorker
     .register('/sw.js')
   }
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you deployed all javascript files with right permissions.